# regex - capture all underscores between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex

In this string(this is not my code, just sample input)

```
var b_1 = goog.require('a_b_b');
console.log(b_1.b);
```

`a_b_b` should be renamed to `a.b.b`, so all underscores inside a `goog.require('...')` statement should be renamed to a `.`.

I came up with this regex:

```
/goog\.require\('(?:[^_]*(_)[^_]*)*'\)/g
```

Explanation:

```
goog\.require\('   literal
(?:                non-capturing group
[^_]*              match anything except underscore
(_)                capture underscore
[^_]*              match anything except underscore
)                  end of non-capturing group
*                  there can be more than one underscore in a goog.require statement
'\)                literal
```

But this only captures the last underscore.
How can I capture all underscores in a `goog.require('...')` statement?

I don't know if it's useful, but I'm replacing the underscores with javascript, so look behinds are not (natively) supported.

To be clear: I only want the underscores inside the `goog.require('...')` statement to be replaced, so the underscore in `b_1` should not be replaced.

Comment: why can't we use `str.replace(/_/g, '.')` here?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That will also replace the `_` in `b_1`, I only want the underscores in `goog.require('...')` to be replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var result = str.replace(/goog\.require\('[^']+'\)/g, function (match) {
    return match.replace(/_/g, '.');
});
```

This first finds all occurrences that match the `goog.require('str')` form and replaces all occurrences of `'_'` with `'.'`.

Comment: That will also replace the `_` in `b_1`, I only want the underscores in `goog.require('...')` to be replaced.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you give an example? Where is the b_1 in the string?

Comment: See my code in the question. Only `a_b_b` should be renamed, while `b_1` should stay the same.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you can just store the `a_b_b` into a seperate variable.

Comment: I cannot make any changes to the code. I receive the code as a string and I want to replace the underscores in the goog.require statements with dots. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!